# Defining a struct function

Tags: c

I have the next code, but qhen I compiled, it appear an erro: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'float'. But it is just exacly as other code i have and examples from Internet but I don't notice the error.

```
#ifndef Deteccion
#define Deteccion
#define acc_TH 12.74
int cont=0;
int pasos=0;
float SF,SL,SLT;

struct Deteccion
{
int muestras;
int pasos;
float frecuencia;
float longitud;
float orientacion;
};

struct Deteccion Detectar(float ax, float ay, float az, float wz)
{
float mag,longitud,frecuencia;
int muestras;
float sum_acc,sum_w,orientacion;
mag=(ax*ax)+(ay*ay)+(az*az);
mag=pow(mag,0.5); 
if(mag>=acc_TH)
{
    muestras=muestras+1;
    sum_acc=mag+sum_acc;
    sum_w=wz+sum_w; 
}
else
{
    cont=cont+1; 
    if(muestras<32)
    {   
        muestras=0;
        sum_acc=0;
        sum_w=0;
    }
}
if(cont==4)
{
    pasos=pasos+1;
    SF=50/muestras;
    SL=sum_acc/muestras;
    SL=pow(SL,0.333);
    SL=0.22*SL;
    SLT=SF+SL;
    orientacion=(0.02*sum_w)+orientacion;
    sum_w=0;
    muestras=0;
    sum_acc=0;
}
}
#endif
```

Comment: Where is `struct Deteccion` defined?  The function is declared to return a value of this type, but I don't see a `return` statement.

Comment: Which line did the compiler say? Since this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you need to be specific about it.

Comment: @dbush I already edit. I forgot half of the code. Now is complete exacly as I have

Comment: Please change the variable and function names to english, so we can actually read into the meaning of it.

Comment: @WeatherVane In line 17 appear the error

Comment: Why is there an include guard anyway? Are you including a *.c* file? You should not do that. Also, why are there some many global variables that apparently don't need to be global? If you have a struct, you can encapsulate the global variables into the struct and then pass it across all functions that you need.

Comment: @JuanBravo you have `struct Deteccion` after you already have`#define Deteccion` in other words, a definition of nothing. Please never duplicate  identifiers, even it you believe they are "local".

Comment: the `pow()` function expects two `double` parameters and returns a `double` value.  The compiler will complain about the assignment of a double value into a `float` variable.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings

Comment: do NOT place a function body inside a header file.   It is a good practice to place function signatures inside a header file.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code. Indent after every opening brace '{'. un-indent before every closing brace '}'. 2) it is considered good programming practice to write #define names in ALL_CAPS. 3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  4) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` or better, both.  Even in the current context, these variable names are meaningless: `ax`, `ay`, `az`, `wz`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `Deteccion` as the *header guard*, you may not use the same identifier for the `struct` tag. Preprocessor replaces `Deteccion` with blank space, so the compiler sees this:

```
struct // <<== Nothing
{
    int muestras;
    int pasos;
    float frecuencia;
    float longitud;
    float orientacion;
};
```

To fix this problem use a different identifier for the header guard:

```
#ifndef Deteccion_H
#define Deteccion_H
```

**Note:** It looks like you are using header guard inside a file that has function implementation. This is highly unusual. Consider restructuring your code so that implementations and declarations are placed in different files.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is you have defined Deteccion as an empty macro first, which explains the compilation error. The compiler sees `struct Detectar(float` which is illegal.

Funny enough, `struct Deteccion` definition works, just seen as an anonymous structure declaration. Although it is useless because not recallable.

General advice: protect against multiple inclusion with that technique only in header files. It is useless in .c files, And use a distinctive naming rule like uppercase plus prefix.

```
#ifndef DETECCION_H
#define DETECCION_H
```

As a convention, macros are generally full uppercase, which avoids problems like you had.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have:

```
#define Deteccion
```

defining "Deteccion" to be nothing, the line

```
struct Deteccion Detectar(float ...
```

is actually

```
struct Detectar(float ...
```

which is an error.